# HBase can't creates its directory in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hbase/hbase_installation.htm) to install `hbase` and `hadoop` but I'm facing a problem.

Everything is fine until the last step

> HBase creates its directory in HDFS. To see the created directory,
>   browse to Hadoop bin and type the following command.
>
> $ ./bin/hadoop fs -ls /hbase If everything goes well, it will give you
>   the following output.
>
> Found 7 items drwxr-xr-x - hbase users 0 2014-06-25 18:58 /hbase/.tmp
>
> ...

but when I run this command I get `/hbase :No such file or directory`

This is my config

**Hadoop configuration**

**core-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>dfs.replication</name >
      <value>1</value>
   </property>

   <property>
      <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
      <value>file:///home/marc/hadoopinfra/hdfs/namenode</value>
   </property>

   <property>
      <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
      <value>file:///home/marc/hadoopinfra/hdfs/datanode</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

**mapred-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**yarn-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.env-whitelist</name>
        <value>JAVA_HOME,HADOOP_COMMON_HOME,HADOOP_HDFS_HOME,HADOOP_CONF_DIR,CLASSPATH_PREPEND_DISTCACHE,HADOOP_YARN_HOME,HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**Hbase configuration**
**hbase-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
   <property>
   <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
   <value>hdfs://localhost:8030/hbase</value>
</property>
   <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
      <value>/home/marc/zookeeper</value>
   </property>
   <property>
       <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
       <value>true</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

I can browse http://localhost:50070 and http://localhost:8088/cluster

How can I troubleshoot this?

**EDIT**

Based on Saurabh Suman's answer, I created the hbase folder but it stays empty.

In hbase-marc-master-marc-pc.log, I have the following exception. Is it related?

```
2017-07-01 20:31:59,349 FATAL [marc-pc:16000.activeMasterManager] master.HMaster: Failed to become active master
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN]
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1411)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.setSafeMode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.setSafeMode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.setSafeMode(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:602)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.fs.HFileSystem$1.invoke(HFileSystem.java:279)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.setSafeMode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.setSafeMode(DFSClient.java:2264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.setSafeMode(DistributedFileSystem.java:986)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.setSafeMode(DistributedFileSystem.java:970)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils.isInSafeMode(FSUtils.java:525)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils.waitOnSafeMode(FSUtils.java:971)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.checkRootDir(MasterFileSystem.java:429)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.createInitialFileSystemLayout(MasterFileSystem.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.<init>(MasterFileSystem.java:128)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.finishActiveMasterInitialization(HMaster.java:693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.access$600(HMaster.java:189)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster$2.run(HMaster.java:1803)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2017-07-01 20:31:59,351 FATAL [marc-pc:16000.activeMasterManager] master.HMaster: Unhandled exception. Starting shutdown.
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN]
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1411)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.setSafeMode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.setSafeMode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.setSafeMode(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:602)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.fs.HFileSystem$1.invoke(HFileSystem.java:279)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.setSafeMode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.setSafeMode(DFSClient.java:2264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.setSafeMode(DistributedFileSystem.java:986)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.setSafeMode(DistributedFileSystem.java:970)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils.isInSafeMode(FSUtils.java:525)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils.waitOnSafeMode(FSUtils.java:971)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.checkRootDir(MasterFileSystem.java:429)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.createInitialFileSystemLayout(MasterFileSystem.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.<init>(MasterFileSystem.java:128)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.finishActiveMasterInitialization(HMaster.java:693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.access$600(HMaster.java:189)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster$2.run(HMaster.java:1803)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Your HDFS seems to be running on port 9000 while your HBase site is trying to connect to port 8030.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The log indicates that HBase has issues with becoming an active master and therefore it starts to shutdown.

My assumption is that HBase was never able to start properly and therefore it didn't create the `/hbase` directory on its own. Further, this would be the reason why the `/hbase` directory is still empty.

I reproduced your error on my virtual machine and fixed it with this modified setup.

---

**OS** *CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511*

**Virtualization software** *Vagrant and Virtualbox*

**Java**

```
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b12, mixed mode)
```

---

**core-site.xml (HDFS)**

```
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>fs.default.name</name>
      <value>hdfs://localhost:8020</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

**hbase-site.xml (HBase)**

```
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
      <value>file:/home/hadoop/HBase/HFiles</value>
   </property>

   <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
      <value>/home/hadoop/zookeeper</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
      <value>true</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
      <value>hdfs://localhost:8020/hbase</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

---

**Directory owner and permission adjustments**

```
sudo su # Become root user
cd /usr/local/

chown -R hadoop:root hadoop
chmod -R 755 hadoop

chown -R hadoop:root Hbase
chmod -R 755 Hbase
```

---

**Result**

After starting HBase with this setup, it automatically created the `/hbase` directory and filled it with contents.

```
[hadoop@localhost conf]$ hdfs dfs -ls /hbase
Found 7 items
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2017-07-03 14:26 /hbase/.tmp
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2017-07-03 14:26 /hbase/MasterProcWALs
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2017-07-03 14:26 /hbase/WALs
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2017-07-03 14:26 /hbase/data
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup         42 2017-07-03 14:26 /hbase/hbase.id
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup          7 2017-07-03 14:26 /hbase/hbase.version
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2017-07-03 14:26 /hbase/oldWALs
```

Comment: I dont have anything set for the hbase.security.authentication in that file. Is it normal?

Comment: When I read the logs, I thought that hadoop wasnt set for simple authentication

Comment: @Marc, i updated my answer. Hope this will help you!

Comment: you have the hbase.rootdir defined twice .. so it takes the first one? If so, then it's not on hdfs.

Answer (score 1):

We need to edit only those thing in configuration files which can't be created by itself. so,you need to manually create the directory in HDFS.
`hdfs dfs -mkdir /hbase`

Comment: Thank you but the folder is still empty. Please see my update

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same issue, and I notice that:
core-site.xml  hdfs://localhost:9000
hbase-site.xml hdfs://localhost:8030/hbase

I changed the port to 9000, and it worked.